# Probability of obtaining at least a 3 and a sum of 4 when rolling two dice

Tags: probability

I want to find the probability of obtaining at least a 3 and a sum of 4

I have the two events:

A = obtaining a sum of 4

B = obtaining at least a 3

$P(A) = \frac{1}{12}$

$P(B) = \frac{11}{36}$

We can figure this out fairly easily that the answer is $\frac{1}{18}$, but why could I not apply the formula $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$?

Comment: Because the events are not independent.  Knowing that you got at least a $3$ on one die guarantees that the sum is $≥4$ for instance,

Comment: Got it thanks... so I'd have to do $\frac{2}{11}\times\frac{11}{36}$

Comment: In general we have $P(A\cap B)=P(A\vert B)P(B)$ which, if the events are independent, becomes $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.

Comment: @hawks10  For this particular problem, I'd say it was easiest to note that the only possible rolls that pass both tests are $(1,3), (3,1)$.

Comment: @lulu Absolutely. Thanks very much. I realized that was the answer. I just wanted to see which formula to use in case of a more complicated problem.